# Where is it appropriate to ask questions about Technical Certifications?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where is the appropriate place to ask questions surrounding technical certifications? Like Microsoft MCP exams and other industry certifications.

I'm referring to questions surrounding exam prep materials, tips on exam format, etc.

It seems obvious that SO isn't appropriate, but I wonder if maybe programmers.stackexchange.com is better? If not, what SE site would these questions be appropriate on?

Comment: Maybe [workplace.SE] is a candidate. I'm about as certain about that one and programmers, which means I'm sceptical. But SO is certainly wrong.

Comment: And as always, read the on-topic page for each site.

Comment: I would hang around in chat to ask those questions. Because the exams change quite frequently (every year or two) and there is so much related study material and not to mention "how to study" is personal opinion, these might not make good questions anywhere.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127816/158100) from ChrisF applies here as well,

Comment: yeah, these types of questions do lean towards opinion, so most questions regarding this topic are likely not appropriate for any SE site; unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Those type of questions are most likely to attract low quality, link-only answers and/or opinions rather then facts.

It is by design that these type of questions are off-topic across the board of Stack Exchange sites, so much it is even in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) of virtually every site:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

(also mentioned by [ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127816/158100)).

I'm pretty confident your question would be off-topic on Programmers (now called [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)) and the suggested option from [Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288647#comment168739_288647) to have a look at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is not going to fly either, given their help center.

Leaves only [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or one of the many sites (Quora, Reddit) that follow a less strict, forum like, format instead of the rigid Q/A found here.